Sampling Locations for minimal variance of a GP
I am working with a Gaussian Process (GP) that uses an isotropic radial basis function (RBF) kernel. I need to find sampling locations $ X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d $ (can be chosen arbitrarily), such that the variance of the GP at the origin $ 0 \in \mathbb{R}^d $ is minimized.
Specifically, I aim to minimize the posterior variance at the origin given by:
$$
\operatorname{Var}[f(0) \mid y] = k(0,0) - k(0,X)^\top \left( K(X,X) + \sigma_{\text{noise}}^2 I \right)^{-1} k(0,X),
$$
or equivalently, to maximize:
$$
k(0,X)^\top \left( K(X,X) + \sigma_{\text{noise}}^2 I \right)^{-1} k(0,X),
$$
where:

$k(x, x')$ is the isotropic RBF kernel function:

$$
  k(x, x') = \exp\left( -\frac{\| x - x' \|^2}{2 \ell^2} \right),
  $$
with length scale parameter $ \ell $.

$k(0,X)$ is the vector of covariances between the GP at the origin and the sample locations $ X $.
$ K(X,X) $ is the covariance matrix between the sample points, with entries $ [K(X,X)]_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j) $.
$ \sigma_{\text{noise}}^2 $ is the variance of the observation noise.
$ I $ is the identity matrix.

I would greatly appreciate any literature tips that tackle this or a similar problem or any tips to find a set of optimal sampling locations for this special case. Due to the symmetry of the problem. An ideal set of locations should be symmetric (?).
Thank you.

This sounds like active learning with GPs. There's plenty of literature on sequential design of experiments which tackles a similar problem where the goal is to minimise the prediction error across a set of reference inputs. In your case, there's only one input, i.e., the origin. You could have a look at the method in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03206 , or this classic: https://www.jmlr.org/papers/v9/krause08a.html . These problems are usually solved numerically by sequentially optimising a set of candidates. I'm not sure if there'd be a closed-form solution for the RBF kernel.
